# Generating an API blueprint documentation from Django/DRF code

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, apiblueprint, apiary.io

Is there any lib/parser which can generate API blueprint documentation (apiary) from Django + Django Rest Framework code? Eg:

```
class UserView(...):
    """
    ## Users list [GET /users]
    + Request (application/json)
        ...
    + Response (application/json)
        ...
    """


class UserSerializer(...):
    """
    ## User (object)
    + id (string)
    + username (string)
    + ...
    """
```

Answer (score 4):

I use DRF Built-in API documentation,the way to achieve this please refer to the link below.and finally get a website like:
[image]

You can use markdown syntax(markdown lib is need) to doc viewset like:

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """
    create: add user.
    list: list user
    retrieve: retrieve user
    """
```

doc `list_route` like :

```
@list_route(methods=['POST'], permission_classes=[AllowAny], serializer_class=None)
def login(self, request):
    """
     login
     <p>【Receive】tel: tel password: password keep_login: Token change
     <p>【Return】200 success 400 failed
    """
```

> [DRF Documenting your API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/)

By the way,now build-in docs's table Description is get form serializer fields's help_text,I change it to label,if you want change it too,tell me and i will post the code related to it again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm working with different kind of developers, and we are using blueprint api only.

Comment: Hi there! I am trying to document my API like this. I am struggling with the description field. How can I add text to it? And is there also a way of customizing the template/schema?

Answer (score 1):

For generating an API blueprint documentation with Django Rest Framework code, you need to you describe your API using a simple markdown-like syntax. That means that you use [Blueprint](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint)  and [aglio](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio) package for example. Otherwise, there are also a number of great [third-party](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/) documentation tools available.

Comment: As i thought, only file with markdown syntax. Maybe it's time to start such kind of open source project :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to `swagger`

for more info see here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/#third-party-packages